# Object variable or With Block Variable not set - Find and Replace Macro - Multiple Find Iterations

Tags: excel, vba, replace

When running the macro I receive the error "Object variable or With block variable not set". I am unsure which variable is not set properly, now how to figure it out.

I have gone through and tried ensuring all my variables were set up properly but I'm pretty sure I'm missing something.

```
Sub NewMonth_Setup()

'
'Find and Replace
'
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fnd1 As Variant
Dim rplc1 As Variant
Dim fnd2 As Variant
Dim rplc2 As Variant
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
'Activates currently selected sheet
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Select
'
'Replaces old table name with new
    fnd1 = InputBox("Old Table Name: _MMYYWS")
    rplc1 = InputBox("New Table: _MMYYWS")
    fnd2 = InputBox("Old Table Name: _MMYY")
    rplc2 = InputBox("New Table: _MMYY")
'
    fndList = Array(fnd1, fnd2)
    rplcList = Array(rplc1, rplc2)
'
' Perform Find/Replace All
    sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
'
MsgBox "I have completed my search and made replacements"
'


End Sub
```

Expected results would take the user's input for two variables and replace them respectively. It is replacing the inputs but it still returns with the error and does not output the MsgBox

Comment: Are you sure the variables are set up properly? Do you really want them mostly to be `Variant`? No `Range` variables?  Looks like you want to also use `String` for the input, no?

Comment: You never define `sht` or `x`.

Comment: Yes I want them variants. This is to change tables monthly and is part of a larger macro. It references tables that were named earlier in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a member call against `Nothing`. You've declared an object variable here:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
```

This reserves a spot in memory where an object reference can be stored, and until that reference is `Set`, VBA understands this memory space to be `Nothing` - in other languages this might be `null` or some similar concept: bottom line is, there's no valid object reference at that address, so VBA raises error 91 when you try to access it... here:

```
sht.Cells.Replace ...
```

This shouldn't need to be done:

```
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Select
```

Instead, `Set` the `sht` object reference:

```
Set sht = ActiveSheet ' or, get a worksheet reference from the Workbook.Worksheets collection
```

And that should fix it... assuming `x` is given a value *somewhere*. Presumably the search is intended to run in a loop? You need a loop construct for that:

```
For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    sht.Cells.Replace ...
Next
```

Comment: Oddly enough that is what I had originally.  This is part of a larger macro and started failing once inserted. I isolated this portion and changed it to the above from suggested. But re-tried suggested once isolated and have success.  Thank you! Now to reintegrate.